# Display array of Json Objects on Screen

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have successfully Query and gathered my Data into an array containing multiple Json Objects.

But my issue is how to display that array on screen when I run the Cloud Function URL?

**Here is my Code**

```
let returnArr = [];
...
...
...

let result:PendingTransaction = {
                               powerpalUser_id: userID,
                               transaction_id: fn.key,
                               transaction_points: rewardTransaction.transaction_points,
                               transaction_status: rewardTransaction.transaction_status,
                               transaction_date: rewardTransaction.transaction_date,
                               transaction_recipient: rewardTransaction.transaction_recipient
                           };

 returnArr.push(result);

 response.status(200).json(returnArr);
```

Comment: What is your front end technology? Web/Android/iOS/... ? How do you want to display this array. In a table?

Comment: It's Web. I just need the JSON Objects to be returned into an Array...

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

In the Cloud Function return the `returnArr` as below:

```
response.status(200).send(returnArr);
```

And in you web page you will get a JavaScript object where the Array `returnArr` will be in the `data` property of this object.

Below is an example of web page which calls the Cloud Function and print in the console, with JavaScript, some of the values of the array items.

You can do whatever you need in this JavaScript, e.g.: populate a table, create a div for each item and write the content, populate a drop-down box, etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SO example</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>

    axios.get('https://us-central1-myprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/date')
        .then(function (response) {

            results = response.data;  // Array

            for (var key in results) {
                if (results.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    // Here use the results object as you wish with results[key].property, as illustrated below with the console.log()
                    console.log(key + " -> " + results[key].powerpalUser_id + " - " + results[key].transaction_points  + " - " + results[key].transaction_status);
                }
            }

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that I use the Axios library for calling the HTTPS Cloud Function but, of course, you can use any other mean that suits your needs.